# Is there an ObserveOnDispatcher for Windows Store Apps?

Tags: asynchronous, system.reactive, windows-store-apps

I'm using reactive extensions (well, trying, learning) in a windows store app. I have a series of async operations that will eventually navigate to an authorization web page for RTM. Given the reading I've done, I would expect to write something like the following:

```
        var result = rtm
            .GetFrob()
            .Select(s => rtm.GetAuthenticationUrl(s))
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Do(uri => AuthWebView.Navigate(new Uri(uri)))
            .First();
```

However, I can't seem to find a method ObserveOnDispatcher, and further there is no Scheduler.Dispatcher property either, leading me to think on a Windows Store application there is something deeper gong on with the main UI thread and how you reference it.

GetFrob, btw, creates an IObservable sequence using Observable.FromAsync (if that helps with this).

BTW, if I remove that line, I fail in the call to the Navigate as posting it from the wrong thread. So, what is the proper thing to do here to make sure I'm back on the correct thread?

BTW, Excuse the ".Do" operation here, I know it isn't "nice", however, I'm still experimenting in throw-away code.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Argh. Apparently I just am not good enough at search. :(

Turns out that adding the nuget package Rx-Xaml includes the proper assemblies for the scheduler, etc. Details can be found on the main [Rx blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/08/15/reactive-extensions-v2-0-has-arrived.aspx). Of course, my app is back to hanging now, but that may be due to something else dumb on my part.